# How to filter a DateTime field when querying MongoDB Atlas from Dart/Flutter

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, graphql, mongodb-atlas

Using MongoDB Atlas, I created a collection and enabled a GraphQL endpoint. I am able to successfully retrieve data from a flutter mobile app using the "graphql: ^5.1.3" [package](https://pub.dev/packages/graphql) as recommended in the [MongoDB docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/flutter/app-services/graphql-api/#std-label-flutter-graphql-api).

However, I am unable to use a DateTime field as a filter. If I pass the DateTime as a variable directly, it fails to be serialized on the client correctly. If I pass the DateTime as a string, MongoDB Atlas complains that a DateTime is required. Note: it is the same if I use toString() or toIso8601String().

Here is the relevant code and error messages for the three scenarios I tried.

```
//GraphQL Schema
{
  "title": "item",
  "properties": {
    "_id": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "start_time": {
      "bsonType": "date"
    },
    "text": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

```
//Scenario 1
start_time = DateTime.now();
const query = r"""
    query($start_time: DateTime!) {
      items(query: {start_time_gt: $start_time}) {
        _id
        start_time
        text
      }
    }
""";
final queryOptions = QueryOptions(
 document: gql(query),
 variables: <String, dynamic>{'start_time': start_time},
);
final queryRes = await client.query(queryOptions);

//Error:
RequestFormatException (RequestFormatException(originalException: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'DateTime', originalStackTrace: 
#0      _JsonStringifier.writeObject (dart:convert/json.dart:793:7)
#1      _JsonStringifier.writeMap (dart:convert/json.dart:874:7)
#2      _JsonStringifier.writeJsonValue (dart:convert/json.dart:829:21)
#3      _JsonStringifier.writeObject (dart:convert/json.dart:784:9)
#4      _JsonStringifier.writeMap (dart:convert/json.dart:874:7)
#5      _JsonStringifier.writeJsonValue (dart:convert/json.dart:829:21)
#6      _JsonStringifier.writeObject (dart:convert/json.dart:784:9)
#7      _JsonStringStringifier.printOn (dart:convert/json.dart:982:17)
#8      _JsonStringStringifier.stringify (dart:convert/json.dart:967:5)
#9      JsonEncoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:345:30)
#10     JsonCodec.encode (dart:convert/json.dart:232:37)
#11     HttpLink._prepareRequest.<anonymous closure> (package:gql_http_link/src/link.dart:175:26)
#12     HttpLink._encodeAttempter.<anonymous closure> (package:gql_http_link/src/link.dart:200:25)
#13     HttpLink._prepareRequest (package:gql_http_link/src/link.dart:180:6)
#14     HttpLink._executeRequest (package:gql_http_link/src/link.dart:129:25)
#15     HttpLink.request (package:gql_http_link/src/link.dart:76:32)
```

```
//Scenario 2: Trying toString()
start_time = DateTime.now();
const query = r"""
    query($start_time: DateTime!) {
      items(query: {start_time_gt: $start_time}) {
        _id
        start_time
        text
      }
    }
""";
final queryOptions = QueryOptions(
 document: gql(query),
 variables: <String, dynamic>{'start_time': start_time.toString()},
);
final queryRes = await client.query(queryOptions);

//Error:
flutter: QueryResult(source: QueryResultSource.network, data: null, context: Context({ResponseExtensions: Instance of 'ResponseExtensions', HttpLinkResponseContext: Instance of 'HttpLinkResponseContext'}), exception: OperationException(linkException: null, graphqlErrors: [GraphQLError(message: Variable "$start_time" got invalid value "2023-03-18 10:31:16.400884".
Expected type "DateTime", found "2023-03-18 10:31:16.400884"., locations: [ErrorLocation(line: 1, column: 7)], path: null, extensions: null)]), timestamp: 2023-03-19 10:31:17.847114)
```

```
//Scenario 3: trying toString() and changing graphql variable to string
start_time = DateTime.now();
const query = r"""
    query($start_time: String) {
      items(query: {start_time_gt: $start_time}) {
        _id
        start_time
        text
      }
    }
""";
final queryOptions = QueryOptions(
 document: gql(query),
 variables: <String, dynamic>{'start_time': start_time.toString()},
);
final queryRes = await client.query(queryOptions);

//Error:
flutter: QueryResult(source: QueryResultSource.network, data: null, context: Context({ResponseExtensions: Instance of 'ResponseExtensions', HttpLinkResponseContext: Instance of 'HttpLinkResponseContext'}), exception: OperationException(linkException: null, graphqlErrors: [GraphQLError(message: Variable "$start_time" of type "String" used in position expecting type "DateTime"., locations: [ErrorLocation(line: 1, column: 7), ErrorLocation(line: 3, column: 43)], path: null, extensions: null)]), timestamp: 2023-03-19 10:33:44.373030)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figure it out. But turns out that the `Datetime` field in Mongodb is using RFC-3339 format [doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/graphql/types-and-resolvers/#scalar-types). Therefore ISO8601 will not work out of the box.

To convert a `Datetime` object in flutter into `RFC3339`. You can do the following.

```dart
DateTime().now().toUtc().toIso8601String();
```